# Firebase onWrite function to return data to client

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I know that callable functions can be used to return data to the web browser but I am using a `onWrite()` trigger function, after which I want to open a toast on the user's browser.

How do I get some data back to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase database triggers can't return data to the client app.  They are executed asynchronously in the background, and are not even guaranteed to execute immediately.   Only callable and HTTP type triggers can return data.

Comment: All right, can I have a callable inside the trigger function?

Comment: No, that won't work at all.  The client app is completely detached from the database function.

Comment: Okay, I'll use Realtime to update a status area on the page by adding a note somewhere. It doesn't have to be instantaneous..